# Unable to send/upload pgp keys to keyservers

Tags: pgp, openpgp

C:\Users\shiny>gpg --send-keys 170AD0000539A3B
gpg: sending key 170AD0000539A3B to hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure
gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure

gpg --send-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com 170AD0000539A3B

also failed with same error

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm having the same

Comment: Updating gpg to 2.2.12 solved this for me.